# Custom google apps login page

Tags: google-apps

Is there a way to change this awful default login page of Google Apps?

[image: login page]

I want to use a custom login page that I will put at login.jmorais.com. Is that possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing same issue then but I found [gLogin](http://www.gloginapp.com/) in Google Apps Marketplace. this app solve my problem. you can also try.

Comment: What application are you referrint to?

Answer (score 1):

The only official way to replace the Google-hosted login page with your own is using SAML Single Sign-On (SSO). SSO replaces Google's user authentication process with your own however it is not trivial to setup or maintain long term.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60224

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation

If you have your Google Apps users stored in Active Directory, another LDAP database or some sort of central database, you can use SSO to authenticate them. One of the most common (and free) ones to use with Active Directory is Active Directory Federation Services 2.0 (ADFS).

Here's a walkthrough describing ADFS setup for Google Apps:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60224

Answer (score 1):

gControl is a plugin that integrates with google apps domain and offers more to customized and track your domain. You can easily customize google apps login page, landing page and so on. You may have a look here:

http://www.cloudcodes.com/gcontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible if you can plugin to the Gapps backend. I haven't tested this myself, but it makes sense to me...

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/a/login.jmorais.com/LoginAction2?service=mail" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="ltmpl"
             value="default">
  <input type="hidden" name="ltmplcache"
             value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="continue" id="continue"
           value="https://mail.google.com/a/login.jmorais.com/" />
  <input type="hidden" name="service" id="service"
           value="mail" />
  <input type="hidden" name="rm" id="rm"
           value="false" />
  <input type="hidden" name="dsh" id="dsh"
           value="2563131929050950430" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ltmpl" id="ltmpl"
           value="default" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ss" id="ss"
           value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="timeStmp" id="timeStmp"
       value=''/>
<input type="hidden" name="secTok" id="secTok"
value=''/>  <input type="hidden" name="GALX" value="UMhpqk5TuQY" />
  <input type="text" name="Email"  id="Email" size="18" value="" class='gaia le val'  />
  @login.jmorais.com  Password:
  <input type="password"
   name="Passwd" id="Passwd"
  size="18"     class="gaia le val"   />

  <input type="submit" class="gaia le button" name="signIn" id="signIn"
           value="Sign in" />
```

I used the view source feature to find the hidden fields from my own GApps-hoste domain. Please let me know how you get on as I am very curious as to how simple this is to do.

Comment: Just go to "View Source" on your Google Apps hosted domain and make the necessary changes. Or see @JayLee's answer below.

Comment: This is what I tried. But its redirects to a page showing "Oops! Your browser seems to have cookies disabled. Make sure cookies are enabled or try opening a new browser window. ".. But everything is fine with browser. Can you please help ?